# Prints the result but does not write it in txt

Tags: python, file, operating-system

```
import os
s = os.listdir("Desktop\mama\qwe")
f = open("asd.txt", "w")
for i in range(0, 100):
    try:
        print(os.listdir("Desktop\mama\qwe\ ".strip() + s[i] + "\Wallets"))
        f.writelines(s[i] + ":" + "\n")
        f.writelines(os.listdir("Desktop\mama\qwe\ ".strip() + s[i] + "\Wallets"))
        f.writelines("\n" + "\n")
    except:
        pass
```

with `print(os.listdir("Desktop\mama\qwe\ ".strip() + s[i] + "\Wallets"))` it works and it writes in console but f.writelines do not seem to work.

Comment: Remove the `try/except` and you might spot an error

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: I think file writing does not work on my pc, I tried this:
`lines = ['Readme', 'How to write text files in Python']
with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)`
and it didnt work

Comment: Didn't work how? The file is empty or doesn't get created? That worked fine for me.

Comment: The file does not get created, even if I create it myself it wont write anything in it.

Comment: Seems like you're looking in the wrong directory then